# Pass template as a parameter into custom component with foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a component that renders table and I need to define cell template, that will be rendered in each row.

```
<my-table params="files: unprocessed">
    <cell-template>
       <span data-bind="text: name" />
    </cell-template>
</my-table>
```

However, the cell-template renders only in the first row. How do I define and use template as a parameter, that will be rendered used inside binding?

```
<template id="my-table-template">
    <table class="table table-striped" data-bind="visible: files().length > 0">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: files()">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: id" />
                <td>
                    <!-- ko template: { nodes: $parent.cellTemplateNodes} -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

js:

```
function getChildNodes(allNodes: Array<any>, tagName: string) {
    var lowerTagName = tagName.toLowerCase(),
        node = ko.utils.arrayFirst(allNodes, function (node) { return node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() === lowerTagName; }),
        children = (node ? node.childNodes : null);

    return children;
}


ko.components.register("my-table", {
    template: { element: 'my-table-template' },
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: (params, componentInfo) => {
            var a = {
                files: params.files,
                cellTemplateNodes: getChildNodes(componentInfo.templateNodes, 'cell-template')
            };
            return a;
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Knockout doesn't check for this, but it expects the nodes passed to the `template` binding to be a true array. That's because the first thing it does is move the nodes to a new parent node. So you should copy the nodes to a new array:

```
return ko.utils.arrayPushAll([], children);
```

There's also a bug in Knockout 3.4.x when using the same node list multiple times, although it would cause a different effect. See https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2187